# How to set an object list to a class?

Tags: c#, vector, arraylist, xamarin

I have a class and I put it on a "List<(Object)>", and I need to remove the first registry of this list and equality to the class, but the methods remove is void, the message appears:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type `void' to`WebPortaoAPI.BleRequest'"

Here's the code:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    List<Object> requestQueue = new List<Object> (20);

    BleRequest currentRequest = null;//Another class

    requestQueue.Add(currentRequest);

    currentRequest = requestQueue.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Comment: this is because the return type of `removeAt` is void

Comment: Why are you using `List<object>` and not a `List<BleRequest>`? More-so, your question is unclear. What do you really need?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with this code, it makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it you're looking for?

```
public class SomeClass{
    ...

    List<Object> requestQueue = new List<Object> (20);

    BleRequest currentRequest = null;//Another class

    requestQueue.Add (currentRequest);

    currentRequest = requestQueue[0] as BleRequest;
    requestQueue.RemoveAt(0);
    ...
}
```

Comment: You're great! =D Just it...
Thanks!

Comment: @questionerthinker: In this case don't hesitate to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The method [`List<T>.RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't return value.
If you need a queue behavior, consider using the [`Queue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx) class instead of the `List<T>`.